# grep only exact matches from pattern

Tags: regex, r

I would like to grep the rownames that match exacly to my pattern `toMatch`.

```
toMatch <- c("I-A", "I-AA", "I-AAA")
dat[grep(toMatch, rownames(dat)), ]
```

dat

```
hsa-miR-10b-5p_TACCCTGTAGAACCGAATTTGTAA_0;I-AA;0;g           3.939829e-01
hsa-miR-122-5p_TGGAGTGTGACAATGGTGTTTGATA_0;I-ATA;0;0         3.942306e-01
hsa-miR-122-5p_TGGAGTGTGGCAATGGTGTTTGAAA_10GA;I-AAA;0;0      3.948047e-01
```

out

```
 hsa-miR-10b-5p_TACCCTGTAGAACCGAATTTGTAA_0;I-AA;0;g           3.939829e-01
 hsa-miR-122-5p_TGGAGTGTGGCAATGGTGTTTGAAA_10GA;I-AAA;0;0      3.948047e-01
```

Comment: you can add the semi-colon to your pattern

Answer (score 5):

You want grepl as it returns a string of T/F. grep/grepl only takes single string as input, it can't take a vector, you can add | (meaning or) between different things to grep.

```
dat[grepl("I-A|I-AA|I-AAA", rownames(dat)), ]
```

Comment: I think you could also write that pattern as `"I-A{1,3}"`

Comment: If you don't add a semicolon as Cath suggested above, you're going to match `I-ATA`, which it's not supposed to. Combining suggestions, `I-A{1,3};` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Library `stringr` is good for manipulating strings,

```
dat <- dat[str_detect(dat$V1, toMatch),]
dat
#                                                       V1        V2
#1      hsa-miR-10b-5p_TACCCTGTAGAACCGAATTTGTAA_0;I-AA;0;g 0.3939829
#3 hsa-miR-122-5p_TGGAGTGTGGCAATGGTGTTTGAAA_10GA;I-AAA;0;0 0.3948047
```

Comment: You don't need the `=="TRUE"`, as `str_detect` already returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Also, you shouldn't quote Booleans, or you'll eventually get caught in a type conversion bug, e.g. `sum("TRUE")` vs `sum(TRUE)`.